# How to use parent selector in SCSS with new Vue 3 deep selector

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs3, vite, quasar-framework

I want to make this code snippet below work, but it's throwing an error.

```html
<style lang="scss" scoped>
:deep(.q) {
    &-badge {
      font-size: 10px;
      padding: 1px 4px;

      &--floating {
        top: -2px;
        right: -2px;
      }
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

[image: Screenshot of the error thrown]

I'm doing this in a project using Quasar | Vue 3 | Vite | SCSS

Answer (score 0):

Sass doesn't understand `:deep`. It thinks you want `&-badge` to mean `:deep(.q)-badge`, which wouldn't be a valid selector.

Comment: Hey, I understand that @Yaman but looking for a workaround, to make this work in Sass.

Comment: I ask on the VueLand official discord server the answer was:
It depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve. Plain CSS is valid scss, so you can always fall back to that if necessary. For the example you gave above I'd seriously consider ditching the nesting and the & and use plain CSS instead. But using nesting and & is possible:
`q-badge {
  :deep(&) {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 1px 4px;  
  }
  
  :deep(&--floating) {
    top: -2px;
    right: -2px;
  }
}`
I'm not convinced that's actually clearer than the non-nested version though.